# What is DFS Search Service?

Tags: depth-first-search

[image]

When I try to type @ via Alt Gr+Q, it opens a search bar called DFSSearchService as it is seen in pictures.

Any idea what is this and how to disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have a haweii laptop. This happened to me yesterday and I solved it by entering the huawei pc manager. You have to click on the four points, then go to settings, then connections and deactivate the options related to file sharing.

Comment: You made my day. Thx.

Comment: I am not sure how more annoying could it be. Thanks a lot.